# Prove there exist infinite value of $n$ such that $p\mid n2^{n}+1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $p$ be an odd prime number. Prove that there exist infinite values of $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that: $p\mid n2^n +1$.

---

$\textbf{My attempt}$: I have proved that $p\mid (p-1)2^{p-1}+1$. Therefore, we first define $n=p-1$, and then $n\mid n2^n +1$ holds. Since by cungruences $p\mid (p-1)2^{p-1}+1$ means that $(p-1)2^{p-1}\equiv -1 \equiv p-1 \pmod{p}$. Now, since $(p,p-1)=1$ because they are consecutive, we can multiply the equation by $p-1$, without any changes in the modulo, and we get $(p-1)^{2}\cdot 2^{p-1}\equiv (p-1)^2 \pmod{p}$. Recall that $p-1$ is the invers of itself modulo $p$ if and only if $p$ is prime. Thus, $$(p-1)^{2}\cdot 2^{p-1}\equiv (p-1)^2 \equiv 1\pmod{p}$$
We multiply again by $p-1$, and therefore: $$(p-1)^3 \cdot 2^{p-1}\equiv -1 \pmod{p}$$
By little's Fermat theorem,
$$(2^{p-1})^{(p-1)^2}\equiv 1 \pmod{p}$$
We conclude that: $$(p-1)^3\cdot 2^{(p-1)^3}\equiv -1\pmod{p}$$
So again we can define $n=(p-1)^3\neq p-1$, and by that we get another different value of $n$, such that $p\mid n2^{n}+1$, and so we proceed til we get infinite different numbers of $n$. $\textbf{Q.E.D}$

- Now, I'm asking if I got it right because I showed an algorithm, such that $p\mid n2^n+1$, for each odd power of $p-1$, but I haven't written that down. Thanks!

Comment: Your statement "−1 is the invers of itself modulo  if and only if  is prime." is false.  $7\times 7\equiv 1 \pmod 8$, for instance. But you never really use that incorrect claim anywhere.

Comment: why? $6\cdot 6 \equiv 1 \pmod{7}$.

Comment: In any case, your argument is correct, but I still think it is better to argue that there is some arithmetic progression worth of solutions.  Why?  Well, there are a lot more terms in an arithmetic progression than in your series.

Comment: The error in your claim is not that it is false for primes, but rather that it is also true for composites.  Indeed, for any $n$ we have $(n-1)^2=n^2-2n+1\equiv 1 \pmod n$ whether $n$ is prime or not.

Comment: @lulu but it is irrelevant because I discuss primes in the modulo. But you right, I should have mentioned that there is some arithmetic progression. But if I would have written this way in the test, do you think I will get the most points?

Comment: I think your argument might be a bit too informal for a test.  Best is to write down an infinite sequence $n_i$ of solutions.  You almost do that, but not quite.

Comment: @lulu I saw that there are some proofs that give an algorithm to find the numbers. But I got what you say. Thank you lulu!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $p\mid n2^n+1$, then $p\mid (n+kp(p-1))2^{n+kp(p-1)}+1$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$, since $2^{p-1}\equiv1$ mod $p$, so as soon as you verify $p\mid (p-1)2^{p-1}+1$, you have an infinite family.

Comment: I would like to see what you think about my way. Is it correct?

Comment: @aasc232, I think your approach can be made to work, but you need to be more explicit about what you mean by "and so we proceed." You are going from $n=p-1$ to $n=(p-1)^3$. But where do you go next? (Also, there's a typo in the congruence when you multiplied again by $p-1$: It should be $\equiv-1$, not $\equiv1$.)

Comment: You write, but I meant that we proceed with this process. It is like I represent an algorithm.

Comment: @aasc232, when I read your proof carefully, I can see that all the basic ideas are there. But if you were my student learning to write proofs, I would still ask you to rewrite it more clearly and be more explicit about the infinite family. There's also one statement that's actually wrong, namely where you say that $p-1$ is its own (multiplicative) inverse if and *only if* $p$ is prime: the "only if" is false. From a (hyper)technical standpoint, this invalidates the proof, because a proof, above all else, must be a sequence of *true* statements. [continued]

Comment: [continued] Please don't be discouraged. Learning to write proofs is a process that takes time. Do (and redo) it enough and you get better at it. And eventually you get *good* at it.

Comment: Thank you so much! Oh you right about the theorem, I confused because my lecturer wrote the theroem as: "$x ∈\mathbb{Z}$  and let $p$ be a prime. Then $x$ is its own inverse modulo $p$ if and only if $x ≡ 1 \pmod{p}$ or $x ≡ −1 \pmod{p}$". So you see why I got confused?

Comment: @aasc232, yes, it's easy to get mixed up between what's necessary and what's sufficient. Sometimes it doens't matter, but sometimes it matters very much. (In the case of the statement "$x$ is its own inverse if and only if $x$ is $1$ or $-1$ mod $n$, it helps to know that the "only if" part of the assertion does *not* hold when $n=8$, since *each* odd number is its own inverse mod $8$. Having a stockpile of simple examples always comes in handy.)

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are establishing the equation holds for all $n$ of the form $n = (p-1)^{2k+1}$ for all integers $k$ i.e., all $n$ that is an odd power of $(p-1)$. You do need to put this in explicitly though.

Your idea looks like it could be correct, except  you should have instead
$$(p-1)^32^{p-1} \equiv -1 \pmod p.$$

The idea is that $(p-1)^{2k+1} \equiv_p -1$ because $(p-1)^{2k+1}$ is an odd power of $p-1$, whereas $2^{(p-1)^{2k+1}} \equiv_p 1$ because $(p-1)^{2k+1}$ is a *multiple* of $p-1$.

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't write my proof right. See now, please.

Comment: Well what you need to make clearer is the infinite family of $n$ that you are generating--$n$ an odd power of $p-1$. That is actually not so clear from your answer, as you don't explicitly say it.

Comment: You are totally right. However, do you agree that the moves in the proof are correct?

Comment: well, aside from that equation with the typo, your claims were true. But reading it again, what was not clear again from your answer is the infinite family of you were referring to.

Comment: I wanted to give them an algorithm, so when they proceed they will get another value of $n$, which is an odd power of $p-1$. If it was a test, and this question would worth - 15 points, how much would you give me? I also want to evaluate in some way.

Comment: Grading is subjective. Your professor may give something very different. But I could only give maybe 5/15 to 8/15 for this. It depends also on the class and whether it is expected that students are good at writing proofs.

Comment: Got you. Thanks!

Comment: @aasc232 don't be discouraged. Proof-writing is quite challenging to learn. The best way to get better is practice! An important and helpful thing to keep in mind when writing a proof is to keep in mind exactly what it is that you need to establish and whether what you have indeed does that. Now a good exercise in fact would be to rewrite your proof as above, using what you got from this thread already.

Comment: I will try. Thank you so much for the help!!!